# Rocker Switch Specs

Tags: switches

I have a product that will be tested for a dielectric test, which says that the rocker switch placed at the beginning or rather the first component after inlet connector, will be exposed to around 1500 VAC and 1700VDC for approximately 1 minute. **Can a rocker switch withstand this voltage? I can't find any electrical specification in datasheets for rocker switch.** They have only mentioned mechanical properties like dimensions etc.

What properties should I look for to select this rocker switch for my product?

Comment: Why does it have to 'withstand'?   If it arcs at overvoltage but doesn't catch fire, is that acceptable?

Comment: what is the meaning of "arcs"?

Comment: 'arc' means make a spark.   That isn't a normal-input-voltage test, so normal operation cannot be required of your device.   What IS required?  If the switch makes a spark or a fuse opens, is that acceptable?

Comment: The dielectric test is probably designed to test *the insulation rating* of the switch - not its ability to switch at that voltage. The test probably involves closing the switch applying 1700 V to both L and N terminals on the device (0 V difference between the two pins) and making sure that it doesn't conduct to chassis or a test probe. (I have never seen this done.)

Comment: @ Transistor that's right!!

Comment: they won't be switching the lines. They just need to test insulation rating by keeping the switch off all the time. So can any rocker switch marked with @230VAC go through this test ?

Comment: 230 V AC is the contact rating. ThreePhaseEel has answered correctly. (I didn't see your comment for a while because you put a space between the '@' and username so the message failed to send.)

Comment: @transistor.. Sorry ... thanks for your efforts !! cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Look for a "dielectric rating" on your switches

Your switch datasheets should (especially if they have a NRTL component recognition) publish a "dielectric rating" for the switch.  For instance, using the [NKK CWSA/CWSB series power rockers](http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/CWS-2.pdf) as an example, they are rated for up to 3kV from contacts to case for 1 minute.  If this rating is greater than your high-pot test, then you are good.

If they don't publish this value, then find a different switch manufacturer that des.

Answer (score 0):

From this link: [enter link description here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/153596/voltage-rating-for-switch-with-high-voltage-but-very-low-current) it seems that toggle switches seem to have a maximum voltage. So I guess it will be equal for rocker switches.

There a sort of voltage 'divider' is used, so I guess you can do something similar. Or use a small control signal through the rocker to send to a transistor to switch on the main circuit.